# Insert one table and update another with shellscript

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql, sh

I have a problem with my shell script. I want to insert data from file to table1(empty) and then, compare table1 with table2 and update some fields.

The first part is correct, but the second part does not work. 
The only way it works is if after the first part I truncate table1 and run the script again.

I want to make everything in one time(insert data and update)

My shellscript:

```
    #!/bin/ksh    
DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
PATH_LD=$HOME/myscripts/script_anuk
    PATH_BIN=$HOME/bin/myscripts/script_anuk
    PATH_LOG=$HOME/log/myscripts/script_anuk


    logfile=$PATH_LOG/script_anuk$FECHA.log
    logfileMod=$PATH_LOG/script_anuk_mod$FECHA.log

    # Insert 

    sqlldr parfile=$PATH_LD/script_anuk_param.par USERID=$CONSQLPLUS

    # Update
      sqlplus -s $CONSQLPLUS << EOF!

     SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

     SET FEEDBACK OFF
    exec declare cursor d1 is select d.book, d.phone,d.pencil from table1 d,table2 n where d.book = n.book; whow number:=0;begin for r1 in d1 loop update table2 set phone=r1.phone,pencil=r1.pencil where book = r1.book; whow := whow + 1;if mod(whow,10000) = 0 then commit; end if;end loop;end;
    exit
    EOF!
```

My .par

```
Par
USERID=/
CONTROL=$HOME/myscripts/script_anuk/script_anuk_param.ctl
DATA=$HOME/myscripts/script_anuk/data1.dat
LOG=$HOME/log/myscripts/script_anuk/script_anuk_param.log
BAD=$HOME/myscripts/script_anuk/error/script_anuk_param.bad
DISCARD=$HOME/myscripts/script_anuk/error/script_anuk_param.dsc
ERRORS=1000000
ROWS=500
DIRECT=FALSE
```

My .ctl

```
Ctl
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE table1
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
(book  , 
phone         ,
pencil)
)
```

Can you help me please? Thank you! :)

Comment: What kind of error, if any, do you get?  Is it just that no rows are updated? How many rows are there in table1 and table2?  Do you ever reach your commit point / count?  Try verifying that you reach your commit point (10000).

Comment: It`s just that no rows are updated. Table1 - 50.000 records. Table2 - 350.000 records

Comment: Have you tried running the sqlldr portion by itself then running the anonymous PL/SQL block separately in SQL*Plus to see if any errors occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking at your anonymous block and I ran it successfully via a SQL*Plus session as such:

```
  1  declare
  2        cursor d1 is
  3        select d.book, d.phone,d.pencil
  4        from table1 d,table2 n
  5        where d.book = n.book;
  6  
  7        whow number:=0;
  8        begin
  9          for r1 in d1 loop
 10            update table2
 11            set phone=r1.phone,
 12                pencil=r1.pencil
 13            where book = r1.book;
 14  
 15          whow := whow + 1;
 16          if mod(whow,10000) = 0 then
 17            commit;
 18          end if;
 19       end loop;
 20       commit;
 21       end;
 22  /
```

Notice I do not call an `exec` before the `declare`, I add a `commit` at the end to ensure all rows are committed before exiting, and I needed a `/` to complete and execute the block.  I think this is the crux of the issue you are having.

You might also want to re-direct STDOUT and STDERR to a file just to capture the SQL*Plus session information.  Try changing your sqlplus line to:

```
sqlplus -s $CONSQLPLUS >>$logfile 2>&1 << EOF!
```

This is not required but could be of assistance in solving your issue.

Comment: The OP's code looks OK; I wouldn't have used `exec` for this just because it stops you splitting the code onto multiple lines, but it's still valid. You only need the `/` if you remove the `exec`. Also SQL\*Plus commits on exit, though again doing that explicitly is clearer. So although this looks better and can be embedded in the heredoc, I don't think it is the crux of the issue.

Comment: Good points @Alex Poole. On the 'commit' I wanted to make sure it was done because it can be overridden in the $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql file with SET EXITCOMMIT OFF in Oracle 11g.

Comment: True, and certainly doesn't hurt anyway; though they say no rows are updated, not just those from the last iteration. Not really clear what's going on though.

Comment: @Alex Poole Agree fully with you.  It is not clear what is going on here.  One would think that the SQL*Plus session would throw an error of some sort.  Thanks for your feedback.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is data

```
drop table table1;
drop table table2;
create table table1 (book varchar2(5), phone varchar2(10), pencil varchar2(10));
create table table2 (book varchar2(5), phone varchar2(10), pencil varchar2(10));
insert into table1 values ('Book1','Phone1','Pencil1');
insert into table1 values ('Book2','Phone2','Pencil2');
insert into table2 values ('Book1','Phone1','oops');
insert into table2 values ('Book3','Phone3','Pencil3');
commit;

select * from table1;

BOOK  PHONE      PENCIL   
----- ---------- ----------
Book1 Phone1     Pencil1   
Book2 Phone2     Pencil2   

select * from table2;

BOOK  PHONE      PENCIL   
----- ---------- ----------
Book1 Phone1     oops      
Book3 Phone3     Pencil3
```

If BOOK is unique in both tables then you can do this in your script instead

```
update table2 t2
set (phone, pencil) = 
  (select t1.phone, t1.pencil
  from table1 t1
  where t1.book = t2.book)
;
```

Caution - if BOOK is not primary key or unique, then this update will fail with an error whenever there are >1 rows in t1 that match a row in t2 on BOOK.

Comment: Thank you but I need data from .par and I need a cursor(commit 10000 récords)